# navigation drawer vs navigation view which is best and what is the diffrence

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview

i m using navigation drawer in old project but i got new project in this project they used navigation view so what is the difference beet been these  two. which is the best for good for customize .

Answer (score 7):

`NavigationDrawer` is a panel that displays the App’s Navigation option from the left edge of the screen.

[image: Image for NavigationDrawer]

and `NavigationView` is the builtin class/tag through which you tell the drawer what it looks like.

`NavigationView` consists of two main elements (these are optional):

1. You have to tell the NavigationView if there is any header layout:

[image: like this have header and menu both]

2. Menu in the `NavigationView`

If you don't want to use both then you don't need to use it. You can simply put your custom code (XML) inside `DrawerLayout`.

An easy example will help you to understand all the game.

Answer (score 1):

Navigation View is a widget provided by the android which you can use inside a Drawer. Navigation View makes it very easy to create a navigation menu inside your app.

Refer this for more:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html

Navigation Drawer is nothing but a container where your navigation menu resides. Either you can use NavigationView for creating a highly customizable menu or you can simply use a listview to provide the menu items.